# Error in comma alignment with Tabulate for Python

Tags: python, alignment, tabular

Using Tabulate for Python to format a Pandas DataFrame as a psql table. This is the tabulate instruction:

```
print tabulate(df,headers=df.columns.values.tolist(), floatfmt=",.2f", tablefmt='psql')
```

And this is what I get:

```
+---------------+---------------+----------------+------------------+
|   Total Value |     Total P&L |     DoD Change |       WoW change |
+---------------+---------------+----------------+------------------+
|  6,132,391.61 |  1,132,391.66 |  142,900.00    |  1,341,983.32    |
|  5,123,830.00 |    123,830.00 |        -125.00 |     12,375.00    |
|  1,762,700.00 |     62,700.00 |   57,950.00    |     81,700.00    |
|  1,746,970.00 |     46,970.00 |  -23,589.30    |           nan    |
|  5,046,650.00 |     46,650.00 |   -7,700.00    |      5,350.00    |
|  4,998,793.08 |     -1,206.92 |           0.00 |             0.00 |
|  4,948,365.06 |    -51,634.94 |         300.00 |      2,870.00    |
|  4,645,100.00 |   -354,900.00 | -106,925.00    |     78,800.00    |
|  4,604,000.00 |   -396,000.00 |           0.00 |             0.00 |
|  4,566,477.00 |   -433,523.00 |  -40,171.50    |   -104,325.00    |
|  4,566,477.00 |   -433,523.00 |  -40,171.50    |   -104,325.00    |
+---------------+---------------+----------------+------------------+
```

For some strange reason numbers <1000 are not aligned by commas.

Comment: By the way, even if I pass the argument numalign="decimal", I still get the same result. Only if I pass numalign="right" everything is properly aligned, but only because I have two decimal points. Which is just a workaround, not a proper solution.

Comment: It looks like this is a bug within the Tabulate library -- somebody [filed an issue](https://bitbucket.org/astanin/python-tabulate/issues/74/decimal-alignment-doesnt-work-with) about it recently. So, until it gets fixed, I think your options are to either use the "align right" hack, settle for not displaying commas, or use a different library altogether. (The fourth alternative would be to contribute a patch to fix this yourself, of course).

Comment: Yes, that issue seems to be exactly the problem. Thanks for the link. Will work around it for now and keep track of the fix. I don't think I am skilled enough to fix it myself ;-).

Answer (score 0):

Try `print tabulate(df,headers=df.columns.values.tolist(), floatfmt=",.2f", tablefmt='psql', numalign='left')`